# React Development Server Not working from subdirectory

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to run react development server from a subdirectory in a given domain, the subdirectory for example is http://example.com/proxy/port/subdirectory. I use create-react-app for setup and project structure. As per the documentation, I am using the following technique to make react work from the subdirectory

1. Define REACT_APP_PUBLIC_URL in .env, the value is http://example.com/proxy/port/subdirectory
2. Use basename in Router in index.js

```
   import {
   BrowserRouter as Router,
   Switch,
   Route,
   Link
   } from "react-router-dom";
   import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
   import './index.css';
   import App from './App';
   import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

   const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
   root.render(

   <Router basename={process.env.REACT_APP_PUBLIC_URL}>
   <React.StrictMode>
   <App />
   </React.StrictMode>
   </Router>
   );
```

3. Add base tag in index.html

   `<base href="%REACT_APP_PUBLIC_URL%" />`
4. Reference other resources relative to the REACT_APP_PUBLIC_URL

   `<link rel="icon" href="%REACT_APP_PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />`

I run my development server like this

```
HOST=localhost npm start
```

When I hit the URL, I can see all resources (favicon, manifest.json) except bundle.js have been referenced properly with absolute URL of the subdirectory, however bundle.js is still referring the root, and because of that it doesn't get downloaded, and I end up seeing blank page as the output.

```
<script defer src="/static/js/bundle.js"></script>
```

Comment: You did not mention what server environment is hosting and serving your app. Check the CRA [deployment docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/) and try to find a section relevant to your server environment. The gist is generally that page requests for sub-routes need to be redirected to the root index.html file so your React app loads and handles the URL path routing internally on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to initiate `<React.StrictMode>` Next You need put `<Router>`

**Try the Code like this**

```
   import {
   BrowserRouter as Router,
   Switch,
   Route,
   Link
   } from "react-router-dom";
   import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
   import './index.css';
   import App from './App';
   import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

   const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
   root.render(

   
   <React.StrictMode>
   <Router basename={process.env.REACT_APP_PUBLIC_URL}>
   <App />
   </Router>
   </React.StrictMode>
   
   );
```

Comment: No, doesn't work.